# clojure.core.async/alts!! - Guaranteed only one channel is operated on?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

When `alts!!` or `alts!` is called, is it guaranteed that only one of the ports are taken from or put into?

```
(let [[value channel] (alts!! [c1 c2 c3 [1 c4]])]
   (cond (= channel c1)
         ; at this point, is it guaranteed that alts!!
         ; did not take from c2 and c3, and did not call (>!! c4 1)? 
         (do-something)))
```

I can't find anything relevant about this in the docs. I am guessing it is undefined?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of alts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `alts!`'s [docstring](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L272) the function "*Completes **at most one** of several channel operations. [...]*".

This means that only one or zero (i.e. it will park) operations will be done on the ports when the function is called. Which operation is non-deterministic, as described in the docstring: "*Unless the `:priority` option is true, if more than one port operation is ready a non-deterministic choice will be made*".